# Native app 404 page not found example

Tags: mobile, ux-designer, native-app

I'm looking for 404 page not found an example for the native app,I would appreciate if someone can provide me with some screenshots for a famous company like facebook,twitter,amazon,airbnb..etc, it easy to find examples for desktop but not for the native app.

Thanks

Comment: Why would a native app not be able to find a page? Do you mean the app is just a webview? In that case, do you just mean a 404 for mobile?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not addressing a usability concept or concern. UX.SE is not the appropriate place to ask to ask for design examples.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think a 404 error is desirable in a native app.

Checkout [Emptystate.es](http://emptystat.es) - either the [errors](http://emptystat.es/tagged/error) or [mobile](http://emptystat.es/tagged/mobile) sections where there are lots of examples of native apps that can be seen to talk less about a '404 page-not-found' scenario, and more about managing a situation of 'no relevant content' in an appropriate and engaging way.

Here's a couple of examples:

[image]

[image]